# Filtering and matching json data in D3.js hover

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive legend that highlights matching villages on a D3.js map according to who owns them. However, the highlight doesn't work. If I change my JSON file to show the village is owned by one person it works, however most villages are owned by multiple people. How can I fix this? Do I need to do something with the JSON?

The interactive legend code goes as follows:

```
//Decrease opacity of non selected circles when hovering in the legend  
function selectLegend(opacity) {
  return function(d, i) {
    var chosen = color.domain()[i];
    d3.selectAll(".villages")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.landholder != chosen; })
      .transition()
      .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
};//function selectLegend
```

The json looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "longitude": 55.4,
    "latitude": 55.4,
    "name": "village1",
    "landholder": ["Landholder1", "Landholder2", "Landholder3"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `chosen` contains only one landholder's name:

If `d.landholder` is an array, then using `d.landholder == chosen` will not work. You will need to see if your value is in the array, not if the value is equal to the array.

Try a line such as:

```
 .filter(function(d) { return d.landholder.indexOf(chosen) > -1; })
```

`array.indexOf(value)` will return the index of the a value in a given array. Negative one indicates that the value is not present. So, for your code, you can see if the chosen value is in the landholder array if `d.landholder.indexOf(chosen)` returns a number of zero or greater.

For this to work, all your landholder values in your json should be arrays, even if they have only one value in them:

```
"landholder": ["Landholder1"],
```

The example below is a simple implementation of this using data elements that have belong to one or more groups (a,b,c,d):

```js
var data = [
 { groups: ["a","b","c"] },
 { groups: ["b"] },
 { groups: ["a","c","d"] },
 { groups: ["a","d"] },
 { groups: ["a","b"] }
]


var text = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data(["a","b","c","d"])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(function(d) { return "Group: " + d })
  .on("mouseover",function(chosen) {
    // reset all circles:
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill","steelblue");  
    // select all circles and filter if groups array has chosen value:
    d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d) { 
        return d.groups.indexOf(chosen) > -1 
      })
      .attr("fill", "red")
  
  })

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200);
  
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx",function(d,i) { return i * 100 + 50 })
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r",20)
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
```

```css
p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I try that line I get the following: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: This would suggest that your d.landholder property is undefined. I've included a simple example in the answer, perhaps that will help. Otherwise can you share a complete or working example at all?

Comment: I went back through all the data related to d.landholder and found some were missing. This solved the problem! Thanks